What does "taking" means here?
Seems stagnant? How so? TAKING new parks, 'Gathering Place' is new and one of the best parks, if not the best park, I’ve ever been to. Tulsa has lots of stuff opening downtown and has a pretty good night life scene.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is close to incoherent.

'Take' is extremely polysemous, so this is not easily ascertained by looking at dictionaries.
Here, it means 'considering' / 'dealing with' / 'taking into consideration [just]' / 'confining our attention to':

'Considering [just] / [for example] new parks, 'Gathering Place' is new and is one of the best parks I’ve ever been to, if not the best.


take:
18a: to deal with

take first things first

b: to consider or view in a particular relation

taken together, the details were significant

especially: to consider as an example

take style, for instance


[Merriam-Webster]

take:

verb ... B2 You use take when you are discussing or explaining a particular question, in order to introduce an example or to say how
the question is being considered.


There's confusion and resentment. Take this office, for example.


[Collins]
